# Need Recommendation for Upgrading from 10.10 to 11.10

Tags: upgrade

I'm ready to finally move from 10.10 to 11.10. I have cloned my existing drive with Clonezilla, so I have a good backup image. My current drive is separated into separate partitions with home and data all separate (somewhat of a legacy setup from when I dual booted). My home and data partitions are rsynced regularly to a NAS. I've definitely done plenty of tweaking and installed lots of apps, and would like to have an easy way of at least keeping track of what I need to reinstall. Process wise, what are the recommendations. I'm prepared to NOT do an upgrade (especially since I would have to do it twice--10.10-->11.04-->11.10.

Below is a snapshot of my current partition scheme.

[image]

Comment: Don't count on keeping your customizations from 10.10 in 11.10. Whatever you did to Gnome 2 will not show in Gnome 3 or should i say Unity and Gnome Shell. You can keep your apps if you don't format the `/` partition though this can cause you trouble as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what is called a "dirty install", since you already have a separate partition for /home. When the installer brings up the partitioning app, instruct it to NOT reformat the partition where /home resides. It will do a full install, but it will not overwrite /home.

Then, you will still have to reinstall your applications, but most of your settings and other configuration will remain intact. I have done this before, and it works pretty well.